# List join on two lists with generic types in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

I am writing a list join function for generic purpose.

What I need to do is to perform joining on `lft` list and `rgh` list with given left key `lftKey` and right key `rghKey`, and assign the corresponding right item to left list's `lftField`.

here is what I had tried:

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=35&ssc=48&pln=35&pc=51&q=210#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwDaYDOMAUhJigDwBQccAKnKDMCgCaFwBKwa0blANIAZADTcA2oK4BdAHxwAZN178hAMXFc4AHzgokePHNG1uTEC3acefKAOnj6U4fNN0RFqxzgBrYACeEAgM7nDSXqw+-kEhXGGC6pHWfoHBDNRyABR4CDDCRDAAXAwSMuJQAOYAFgXEJVxl4rkwgoElIhU1bQEd8fh56pjAeGwd6gCUJc4ycADeZnwoxHBQwITTZXAAvHBlANxmCNBwOcDwLXDpLXUwE-NmdEsrVdU7qzW3AHQIFGxZWSg922CigElePVm22hAxgEhakImhzodEwIUBNXuCxRKLWhC+YCQhGqWTmcC+FJa4nhg2GoxkJVecAAvkjHiymHhCMAHji6HiCUSSS02TjmWZxfzzkgoLg8YdxdQAPRKiwAQwAtmA8MBqNQYAEwDyAPJVNUoTAALzVWBw72xcEwY30SA1ACNgFBkfpNcASsQoBRKgq9QajXAAKrcqD2szQSoASWdBndnu98ZKpsq5qtNuwuD0BiM3qdJRTHq91EVzwueRKUc9W12Ejm8aTJQAjOIMy6jOJS3AO8zxK2qu24AAmbtVMuGPD950T4fzNvOgDM08qs77jvXzJk1BrH2qmbNFuttpQTb2cwHXZ9Gr9cAA5PGALRq5-L2+L8QoX0lK+VRvm6X4HkeeLvAQxBkBQOR5F01TiEBiZsM+yFOuhL7xs+ExAA)

```
export function listJoin<
  T extends Record<KL, R[KR]> & Record<KF, R | null>,
  R extends Record<KR, T[KL]>,
  KL extends keyof T,
  KR extends keyof R,
  KF extends keyof T
>(lftList: T[], rghList: R[], lftKey: KL, rghKey: KR, lftField: KF): T[] {
  const res: T[] = [];
  for (let lft of lftList) {
    const rgh = rghList.find((r) => r[rghKey] === lft[lftKey]);
    if (rgh) {
      res.push({ ...lft, [lftField]: rgh });
    } else {
      res.push(lft);
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

I got a syntax error:

```
This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types 'R[KR]' and 'T[KL]' have no overlap.ts(2367)
```

Example usage:

```
type Organization = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

type User = {
  orgId: number;
  org: Organization | null;
  id: number;
}

const lft: User[] = [{orgId: 1, org: null, id: 1}, {orgId: 2, org: null, id: 2}, {orgId: 3, org: null, id: 3}]
const rgh: Organization[] = [{id: 1, name: 'org-a'}, {id: 2, name: 'org-b'}]
const res = listJoin(lft, rgh, 'orgId', 'id', 'org')
// Expect result: 
// res === [{orgId: 1, org: {id: 1, name: 'org-a'}, id: 1}, {orgId: 2, org: {id: 2, name: 'org-b'}, id: 2}, {orgId: 3, org: null, id: 3}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify this problem to this:

```
function genericCompare<A, B>(a: A, b: B) {
  return a === b
  // This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types 'A' and 'B' have no overlap.(2367)
}
```

Same error message, for the same reason. Typescript assumes that `A` and `B` are differnt types, or put another way, are different subtypes of `unknown`.

Typescript is actually a bit too strict here. `A` and `B` may be different types `genericCompare(true, { a: 123 })` in which case this type error makes sense, but they may also be the same type `genericCompare(123, 456) in which case this comparison is valid.

---

I think it's best to simply widen one of these parameters to `unknown`.

```
function genericCompare<A, B>(a: A, b: B) {
  return a === b as unknown // fine
}
```

Now in the comparison `b` is not type `B`, but it could be *any unknown type*. So Typescript allows the comparison without issue because now it can see that it *might* be the same type.

Despite the type assertion, this does not actually make your code less type safe. You can always *widen* a type with an `as` type assertion with no loss of type safety, but when you use it to narrow a type then that is when you may lose type safety.

And going whatever `B` is to `unknown` is widening since you're saying `B` could be a wider set of things.

---

Now back to your code, if you change the offending line to this, it should work for you:

```
const rgh = rghList.find((r) => r[rghKey] === lft[lftKey] as unknown);
//                                                        ^ added type assertion
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&q=210#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZlQJxhAwnAWwAcBDTVAHgEEAaRAIQD4AKEgLkVsQCMP6BKRAG8AUIkTkoITEhKIAvIp6ISAZ0TgA1mDgB3MCIC+IkaEiwEiADYxVUAFJwYYCmMQAZRKgAeUdABN1ACVUCDhMfwoAaXc6IIBtKKCAXUZEADJEELCI6IAxOMQAH0QwECsrRho3IK9fAODQ8MikundE91Tq8Ri6vzBAxE1UAE84YA9uxCS+hqHR8aypqLzZgfVhsYn3ERYrYCh3WygOduS6TGQACyO7DgTz6wOo0Y4Yi+uXkbegun2oPIwVBWfxvPL8U7xZLCNxhMB2CSoVSQ6HyRBQgDcbmA4UQzCsqCgTyJi3+tygglE4nEcIRlyuCgk13JADpgM5-MxmJhBPI0ph4vSvqilP94v9hSp1FodPp+FjqYgYBNuddKW5FeRVCyiCBVFdmEJECyTf86OKDoDgf5khx6YhDPKNQ6vFZVKgYYrxFqdXqDf8nYrjOJg4ipDJEaoscYRFARkQPQB5S4kMAwABeJAsSDRVKVoNKIAI3CwCtKJAIqA4dmwYGQ0ZMcYTiAAqu7MIy8+FkABJAtlYultzdjjJ5CpjNZ+BIEplCplmD9oslzANkS0on-DhtrBQxnxITdvscACMdBHhYqdEXp8MdEPl2PiAATOfLhw51ZrwXn3fhEeCwAZjfZAP3KL98w4QDDGSdcEDpa5RxTNNM2zPc0QPG9EDPctKw4ABybsAFoSHwv8hCw19cKrRBCMuIjuDI2CN0jRkbDsRxnHxA4PiuOg6N7fx8P4xdhNo7t8P4EQAHppMQABRbwE2gSNyhORAZLkrUFCUA8ANPECOAogscLACsaIEkiyO-W9730l9DOESi6DMvDxPoxi-0o8j7OAxAL0-GzEGg2C4PhOACRZKw4GQbkkX4IA)

---

There's another, complicated, way of making sure your constraints are such that

Comment: so that means it is safe to compare `unkonwn` with any other type in ts?

Comment: Sure. "safe" means won't crash or lead to incorrect assumptions about the types of your values. So it's "safe" to compare any values in Typescript regardless of type, but Typescript also has some logic that prevents you from making mistakes, which includes letting you know that you are comparing two different types. In this case you are sure that's not a mistake, and widening a type is always safe, so you can widen the type.